# How do I draw just one channel of a waveform in Praat?

Tags: phonetics, acoustic-analysis, praat

I have a nice 2-channel recording in Praat. I want to illustrate the waveform for an article, but when I select file>draw visible sound, the result is both channels. Is there any way to adjust this so just one of the two channels appears? Otherwise I use space unnecessarily and, since I want to compare a few different waveforms, one after another, it gets confusing fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the objects window, choose

`Convert > Convert to mono`

This converts your recording from stereo to mono by overlaying the two channels. Then draw as usual.

If the two channels differ substantially and you want only one of them (instead of a mixture of both), you can load the recording into [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and split the stereo track into two mono tracks.

Comment: You don't need to split the different tracks in Audacity. You can do that directly from Praat using `Convert > Extract one channel...`

Answer (score 2):

You can either downmix it to mono, or delete one channel. choosing one over the other depends on your situation. if your channels are identical you can delete one, if your channels are not identical you can downmix them in one channel so that you will not lose any data.

To downmix your audio in Praat go to `Convert - Convert to mono`

To extract one channel, and obviously delete the other one go to `Convert - Extract one channel`